# Ajax Interface menu choice - never seen before

Tags: joomla-3.x

On a new install of Joomla 3.6.2 with a purchased template there is a menu option in the Adminitrator labeled "Ajax Interface" under Components which I've never seen before.

If I select it the following error message appears:

InvalidArgumentException: Please specify a valid response format, other than that of HTML, such as json, raw, debug, etc.

How can this be corrected as the site is working properly otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This menu item shouldn't appear in your Joomla backend (3.6.2), no idea why it's appearing for you. Having said that, the Ajax Interface is a core Joomla extension that is responsible for simplifying Ajax implementation in Joomla. You can read more about it [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-use-joomlas-ajax-interface-component-com_ajax).

Comment: I removed the entry in the db with no apparent bad effects.